# How to do work up of reactions (Problem of Emulsion) where NO2 group is reduced using SnCl2.2H2O?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I did a reaction where I have reduced Nitro group to -NH2 group. I have added solid NaHCO3 and shifted pH to 10 as reported in procedure. While extraction emulsion is forming so how to overcome the emulsion issue?

[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv90s.png)

[image: Reaction]

Answer (score 4):

I have run this reaction many times on a variety of substrates.

The solution to this is to keep adding base, preferably hydroxide rather than carbonate/bicarbonate (I used 50% aq NaOH), until the tin salts start to go back into solution and you get good phase separation.

And don't forget to extract your aq. phase a couple of times.

note: the reaction works perfectly well using EtOAc as solvent

Comment: Or, chemically speaking, the OP has to overcome the formation of amphoteric $\ce{Sn(OH)2}$ to $\ce{[Sn(OH)3]^{-}}$ and $\ce{[Sn(OH)4]^{2-}}$.  Though $\ce{[Sn(OH)3]^{-} + 3 OH^- -> [Sn(OH)6]^{2-} + 2 e^-}$ with a potential of $\pu{- 0.93 V}$ is a remarkable reducing agent, too.